# получить поля выделенной строки в компоненте TreeView

Tags: gtk, gtk3

Имеется таблица с данными в модели ListStore. Данные отображаются компонентом TreeView. При наведении курсора на строку она становится выделенной. Каким образом получить доступ к полям этой выделенной строки?
Пытался это сделать следующим фрагментом кода на Си:

```
GtkTreeSelection *psel;

GtkTreeIter iter;

GValue value;

char *pstr;

gint num;

//
psel=gtk_tree_view_get_selection( (GtkTreeView*)(pTreeView) );

//ничего не выбрано

num=gtk_tree_selection_count_selected_rows(psel);

if ( num<1 ) return;

//

gtk_tree_selection_get_selected (psel,(GtkTreeModel**)(&pModel)),&iter);
//
//здесь появляются ошибки

gtk_tree_model_get_value((GtkTreeModel*)(pModel) ,&iter,0,&value);
pstr=(char*)g_value_get_string(&value);
gtk_label_set_text(pLabel,pstr );
```

Как я понял, я что-то делаю неправильно. По идее, я должен иметь возможность получить доступ к выделенным полям через pTreeView, а не через модель. Модели ведь может вообще не быть. По документации понять ничего не могу. И в интернете ничего не нашел. А ведь задача тривиальная.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0):

Нашел в документации https://www.opennet.ru/docs/RUS/gtk-reference/ ответ на свой вопрос. В модели есть доступ к полям через итератор. В моем случае это так:

```
GtkTreeSelection *psel;

GtkTreeIter iter;

GValue value;

char *pstr;

gint num;

//
psel=gtk_tree_view_get_selection( (GtkTreeView*)(pTreeView) );

//ничего не выбрано

num=gtk_tree_selection_count_selected_rows(psel);

if ( num<1 ) return;

//

gtk_tree_selection_get_selected (psel,(GtkTreeModel**)(&pModel)),&iter);

char *psId,*psNm;

gtk_tree_model_get((GtkTreeModel*)(Guide.pStore[0]),&iter,0,&psId,1,&psNm,-1);
gtk_label_set_text(Guide.plbIdSrv,psId );

gtk_label_set_text(Guide.plbNameSrv,psNm);

g_free(psId);
g_free(psNm);
```

Answer (score 0):

Лучше конечно использовать [документацию по GTK+3](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/)  Документация конечно полная но на английском и некоторые веши не очевидны.

Например информация по *GtkTree*

```
GtkTreeModel * tree_model; 
GtkListStore * list_store;
GtkTreeModelFilter * tree_model_filter;
GtkTreeModelSort * tree_model_sort;
GtkTreeStore *tree_store;
```

Вроде разные структуры и разные функции но

```
tree_model = (GtTreeModel*) list_store;
tree_model = (GtTreeModel*) tree_model_filter;
tree_model = (GtTreeModel*) tree_model_sort;
tree_model = (GtTreeModel*) tree_store;
```

В полне законое действие.

И во всех функциях

```
gtk_tree_model_*();
gtk_tree_model_filter_*();
gtk_list_store_*();
gtk_tree_store_*();
gtk_tree_model_sort_*();
```

Можно использовать один указатель.

При этом, `GtkTreeView` может быть перерисован не всегда явно, даже небольшое изменение структуры может сильно перерисовать все дерево.